# Android: Mobile data access

Tags: android

How can i find out in Android if mobile data access is enabled in the settings ?programmatically, Should i consider this true if NetworkInfo.state is DISCONNECTED ? or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use networkinfo (either `isConnected()` or `isConnectedOrConnecting()`,
depending on what fits your needs)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html

Comment: isConnected is only for network info, but i guess for data access we have to see the stat like this NetworkInfo.State state = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();